# Is there an emulator for the original Xbox?

Tags: emulator

Is there an emulator for the very first Xbox? Been looking through links for emulators on Google but it seems like those ones lead to really fishy sites that are cited by NeoGAF as fake or they just don't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Original Xbox emulation at the time of writing is very crude/experimental.

The most advanced emulator, and to my knowledge the only one actively in development, is [Cxbx](http://www.emucr.com/search/label/Cxbx?&max-results=12)

However, even that is little more than an early alpha. It can run (badly) a few games (there's no official compatibility list, but you can count the games that actually somewhat work on the fingers of one hand).

All in all, if your aim is to actually play xbox games on your computer you're out of luck for the time being.